# SQL Excluding Values of Condition

Tags: sql

I'm Learning SQL and I have a basic problem that I couln't  resolve yet. I have this code.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) FROM people AS p
JOIN stars AS s
ON p.id = s.person_id
WHERE s.movie_id IN
    (SELECT s.movie_id FROM stars AS s
     JOIN people AS p
     ON s.person_id = p.id
     WHERE p.name = 'Kevin Bacon' 
     AND p.birth = 1958)
ORDER BY p.name ASC;
```

The result are 177 rows including the value of the condition 'Kevin Bacon'. But I need to query the result of  176 rows without considering the  value of the condition that I'm using, in this case 'kevin Bacon'.

Comment: Please post code as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: That seems to be an odd requirement. Someone spelled kevin with a lower case k, and you think that movie has another actor, not Kevin Bacon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,  I didn't about all the issues created when using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be using SQL Not Equal (<>) Operator can help you. You can do something like

```
WHERE p.name = 'Kevin Bacon' 
  AND p.birth = 1958 
  AND p.name <> 'kevin Bacon'
```

in the second last line of your SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!I  use the Not Equal operator  with the WHERE clause outside the subquery.